# Autocomplete feature for Atom editor custom node js modules

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, editor, atom-editor, ternjs

I have installed Ternjs package which is for providing autocompleting feature for javascript in Atom editor. Also enabled this in my project via Packages -> Atom Ternjs -> Configure Project.

did a Restart Server.

Basic node js module code are displayed based on autocompleting feature when I type code in the text editor, whereas third party nodejs module's code such express, mongodb not suggested

**.tern-project**

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [],
  "loadEagerly": [],
  "dontLoad": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ],
  "plugins": {
    "doc_comment": true,
    "node": {
      "dontLoad": "",
      "load": "",
      "modules": ""
    },
    "angular": {}
  }
}
```

Below screenshot shows that autocomplete works for inbuilt modules of node js. I have used filesystem module
[image]

Below screenshot show that autocomplete not working for express module (3rd party) of node js platform.
[image]

Much appreciated any help to resolve issue in Atom Ternjs package.

Answer (score 2):

After amended line `dontLoad: []`. It worked fine.

**.tern-project**

```
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "libs": [],
  "loadEagerly": [],
  "plugins": {
    "doc_comment": true,
    "node": {
      "dontLoad": "",
      "load": "",
      "modules": ""
    },
    "angular": {}
  },
  "dontLoad": []
}
```

latest file that worked well.

Answer (score 2):

it is extemly suggested to check "browser" under "libs" as shown:
[image]
[image]